# How to load, compile, and call a JRuby file, from Java?

Tags: jruby, jruby-java-interop

The best doc I found was [this](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyAndJavaCodeExamples), but it's a bit outdated -- deprecated or missing methods. I'd like to, from Java code:

1. Load a `.rb` file from the filesystem.
2. Make sure it is compiled to the fastest form possible, since this exists in a long-running server.
3. Call a function or class in that file, passing in values constructed on the Java side.
4. (If possible) Be able to repeat steps 1-3, if the `.rb` file changes, and pickup the new Ruby code.